# How to search an entire CVS repository (all branches/history/comments)?

Tags: version-control, search, cvs, grep, history

If I want to essentially grep every line ever in the repository, is there a way to do it? I know this would take a long time for large projects.

If not all inclusive, at least just the current branch and its entire source history?

Edit: I should have been more explicit. **What if I don't have direct access to the server that the CVS repository is on?** So I couldn't *directly* grep the filesystem that has the CVS repository.

Comment: Not having access to the repository is a pretty big thing to have omitted, don't you think? However, unless you're using pserver, or your IT department has gone to extreme lengths, you probably do have access to the repository - just not convenient access. Please edit your question and add the contents of the CVS/Root file (you'll find it in any directory in your working tree). Replace any hostname reference with foo.example.com if you don't want people to know anything about your network, and replace directory names if needed. But don't change anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the standard CVS set up is. I've been using subversion for so long, and the last time that I used CVS was more than 8 yrs ago. I am using pserver. I tried sshing on the host, but no luck. I'll inquire about setting up an account, since that seems like the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're looking for. CVS version files contain all of the edits that have ever happened to the file, in plaintext. So if you're simply looking for all files that contain a particular word, do a recursive grep on the repository.

If you're looking to find specific versions that contain those words, then you're going to have to extract the versions from the repository, which is expensive. However, if you can limit the set of files by grepping the repository, then it's not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with standard CVS tools without access to the repository. A third party tool out there may do it (I don't know of one, although CS-CVS seems to [claim to](http://www.componentsoftware.com/products/cvs/wincvs.htm)), but to do it programatically, you would have to do CVS logs on all the relevant files, and then retrieve and search each version reported by cvs in the logs (cvs log is a command line option in CVS that shows you the revision history of any file, but it doesn't show you the contents).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I recently used, in a case where I didn't have access to the server. It seemed to work that time. Call it from inside a working copy, with cvs in the PATH. Note that this doesn't search commit messages, but you can simply grep 'cvs log' for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Searches CVS diffs and first revisions behind the current working
# directory for an expression (perlre syntax).

# Synopsis: cvsgrep [-n] <search-expression> [<file_1> ... <file_n>]

# -n means that contents of matching files should not be printed to stdout.

use Getopt::Std;

my %options=();
getopts("n",\%options);
my $no_content_dump=$options{"n"};

my $search_term=shift
    or die "Error: usage is: cvsgrep [-n] <search-expression>".
    " [<file_1> ... <file_n>]";

sub quote_fn
{
    my $fn=shift;
    $fn =~ s/\'/\'\"\'\"\'/g;
    "'".$fn."'";
}

my $args_str;
while(@ARGV)
{
    my $arg=shift;
    $args_str.=' ' if $args_str;
    $args_str.=&quote_fn($arg);
}

print 
    "Searching for term: $search_term",
    ($args_str?" in: $args_str":""),
    "\n";

open CVSLOGH,"cvs log -N $args_str|" or die "Cannot execute cvs log: $!";

my @files_revisions=();

my $cur_file;
my $cur_revision;

while(<CVSLOGH>)
{
    chop;
    if(/^Working file\:\s*(.*)$/)
    {
        $cur_file=$1;
        $cur_revision='';
    }
    elsif(/^revision\s+(.*)$/)
    {
        $cur_revision=$1;
    }
    elsif((/^\=\=\=\=/ || /^\-\-\-\-/) && $cur_revision)
    {
        push @files_revisions,{file=>$cur_file,rev=>$cur_revision};
    }
}

close CVSLOGH;

my $matchcount=0;
my $count=0;
my $progress_msg="Scanned %d out of %d commit(s)\r";
my $erase_ln=(" " x (length($progress_msg)+20)) . "\r";

foreach my $file_revision(@files_revisions)
{
    printf($progress_msg,$count++,scalar(@files_revisions));

    my($file,$rev) = ($file_revision->{file},$file_revision->{rev});

    $rev =~ /^(.*\.)([0-9]+)/;
    my $revbase=$1;
    my $revlastdigit=$2;
    my $rev1=$revbase.($revlastdigit - 1);
    my $diffcommand = "cvs diff -N -r $rev1 -r $rev ".&quote_fn($file);
    open CVSDIFFH,"$diffcommand|" or die "Cannot execute cvs diff: $!";

    my $diffresult;
    while(<CVSDIFFH>)
    {
        if(/^[\<\>]/)
        {
            s/^.//;
            $diffresult.=$_;
        }
    }
    close CVSDIFFH;

    if($diffresult =~ /$search_term/s)
    {
        print "${erase_ln}FOUND: in diff for $file $rev1:$rev\n";
        $matchcount++;
        system($diffcommand) unless $no_content_dump;
    }
}

print "${erase_ln}Done ($matchcount match(es)).\n";
```